# Facebook Unity SDK iOS login is not using system level login but uses browser or facebook app

Tags: ios, authentication, facebook-unity-sdk

I have encountered an issue where a facebook user is logged in from within iOS 7.1 itself (from Settings app). My app is ignoring this system level log in, and instead is switching to the facebook app (if installed), or web browser to log in the user. From facebook developers dashboard, under iOS settings I have entered the correct bundle identifier, and also enabled Single Sign On.
Also in the Settings app, there is no switch for my app to allow it to use the facebook account.

I'm using Facebook Unity SDK 5.1 and Unity 4.3.0f4

(P.S. On Android it works fine and uses the system level login)

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue?

Comment: Nope. I have a hunch that it is by design of facebook Unity SDK, so it switches to their facebook app, and they have control on the UI of how to present permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your URL scheme suffix isn't set up correctly. If you press open the Facebook menu on the top bar in unity and click edit settings it will open your Facebook settings.

Within this window put "fb" + appId e.g. fb0123456789 into the URL scheme suffix box. Then instead of hitting build and run to test, just press build so that your post processes will make this change in your plist.

Comment: That fb+appId key is already in the info.plist and set correctly :(

Comment: I had the same problem. I deleted the entire xcode project and put the URL scheme into the settings and the checked it in the plist. I was getting a log before that was saying gb+appID+fb+appid is not registered so mine was doubled up some how.

Comment: This did't solve the issue. Settings are correct. On another device (iOS6) it is showing the switch in the settings. But still switches to facebook app.